# Force Datatype in ActiveRecord with Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm running a query with joins and conflicting column names.  IE:

```
results = TableA.joins(:table_b).select('table_a.id as table_a_id', 'table_b.id as table_b_id')
```

In my result, table_a_id and table_b_id are both strings.  What can I do to make them integers?

I feel like theres probably a way to get this to return `results[0]['table_a']['id']` and `results[0]['table_b']['id']` where both have the correct datatype, but I don't know how to do it.

My primary concern is making it so I can access both columns without running a second query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I do this :

```
comments = Comment.joins(:project).select('comments.id as table_a_id, projects.id as table_b_id')
```

And I could do this :

```
comments.first.table_a_id
```

To convert column in integer you can use sql functions. To convert in integer you can use sql or ruby functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dougui's answer pretty much covers accessing both columns, I'll just address string-to-integer conversion.
You have two options, converting in SQL or in Ruby.

In Ruby, you can call `.to_i` on a string to turn it into an integer, thus:

```
> foo = '156'
=> '156'
> foo.to_i
=> 156
```

In SQL, you use the `CAST` function, thus:

```
SELECT CAST('156' AS INTEGER);

 int4 
------
  156
(1 row)
```

Comment: So my issue is that when I `.select()` specific columns, even the integer typed columns come back to Rails as strings.  Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Hm, yeah, that does seem to happen. Never noticed it before. I guess you're stuck doing your string to integer conversions after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but maybe it could be useful.

I ran in the same issue, I solved doing something like this:

Starting from the answer from @Dougui, you can force the `table_b_id` type defining:

```
class TableA
  def [](name)
    if name.to_sym == :table_b_id
      super.to_i
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if name.to_sym == :table_b_id && args.empty? && !block_given?
      super.to_i
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```